# Как найти ошибку на стороне сервера, при добавлении новой записи, перезаписывает предыдущую CMS Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, vesta

Возникла такая проблема при добавлении новой записи к примеру в блог, вместо добавления новой перезаписывает предыдущую, думал не хватает выделенного места в БД, очистил базу на 4 гига, не помогло.
При переносе сайта на хостинг все работает.
На данный момент сайт лежит на VPS, Операционная система: Debian 8, панель управления Vesta

Возможно кто то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой, буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: в базе какая-то проблема. не увеличивается счетчик на автоинкрементном поле wp_posts.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при добавлении новой записи к примеру в блог, вместо добавления новой перезаписывает предыдущую

Подобная проблема наблюдалась если на севере неверно настроен Cache-Control.

В этом случае может помочь такой костылёк:

```
 function add_pragma_no_cache_header( $headers ) {
    $headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
    return $headers;
}
add_filter( 'nocache_headers', 'add_pragma_no_cache_header' );
```

Но лучше правильно настроить кеширование.

Или имеет место быть конфликт с каким-нибудь плагином-"оптимизатором".